# How to update a shared workbook with changes from others before active user data is entered into the sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a shared macro-enabled workbook used to conduct quiz. I have the option to configure users that can access the quiz with the help of computer names. Everything is working fine. However, I would like to introduce a feature to log major things done in the workbook. User does not enter anything manually into cells. All entries are made using userforms.

I have made a sub, which runs every time user performs an operation that I need to capture. The code works like a charm when a single user is active. The problem occurs when multiple users are accessing the file at the same time.

The problem is, user is shown a prompt to choose which change to win on closing the sheet. I don’t want this to happen. Is there anyway by which the prompt can be removed and make all changes saved.

Is there any workaround for this. Below is the code that I have now.

```
Sub Actions()
    QA_Quiz_Master.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    UN = Evaluate("=UserNameWindows()")
    QuizN = Sheet4.Range("F2").Value
    totlog = Log.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Select Case Action
        Case "Open"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Accessed"
        Case "Start"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Started Quiz"
        Case "Submit"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Submitted Quiz"
        Case "AdminContact"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Contacted Admin"
        Case "AccessRequest"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Sent Access Request"
        Case "Publish"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Published Quiz"
        Case "Republish"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Republished Quiz"
        Case "Withdraw"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Withdrew Quiz"
        Case "AnsPublish"
            Log.Range("C" & totlog).Value = "Published Answers"
    End Select
    Log.Range("A" & totlog).Value = UN
    Log.Range("B" & totlog).Value = QuizN
    Log.Range("D" & totlog).Value = Now()
    Log.Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    QA_Quiz_Master.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This critical sentence doesn't make sense: "user is shown a prompt to choose which change to win on closing the sheet". What does "which change to win" mean? Is the prompt you are seeing from windows that says the file is in use? Or is the prompt from your program with some message about "winning"?

Comment: @jdh: It's the prompt which means whether Excel should accept your value or other user's value in a cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I myself got the problem solved. I just needed to add the following code at the beginning of the sub

```
If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    QA_Quiz_Master.AcceptAllChanges
    QA_Quiz_Master.Save
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting the workbook to Shared, look at the Advanced tab. By default it updates changes when the file is saved but you can choose to have it automatically update changes every x minutes. You can also choose if you want Excel to ask which changes win or if you want to automatically save the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Workbooks are a nightmare! One should always avoid using them. I realized this when I was working as an Ops Manager couple of years back. I wanted my managers to update a shared Report at the end of the day and trust me it was a disaster.

Here is an alternative.

Use Excel Userform as a Front End (i.e if you need to use Excel) and use Access Database as a Back End. If Excel is not a concern then port everything to MS Access. I see that you are conducting a quiz here. MS Access is a much better option here.

If you want to pursue the above idea then do let me know and I can explain it in detail :)

The other alternatives that I have used to collect data is displaying a webpage on the INTRANET and storing the results in Access/SQL database.

Comment: I too know that shared workbooks are a nightmare. In my case all the functionalities works good. Only issue is the one that I have described here. Thanks for your support and advice. I don’t know MS Access. However, I will certainly try to learn it.

Comment: Unfortunately the last user saving always wins if he chooses to... And hence the above recommendation.